# Number of paths in a rectangular grid with obstacles, after blocking one cell

Tags: algorithm

Given a square grid of size `NxN` with each cell being empty or having an obstacle, block only one cell so as to minimize the number of paths from top left to bottom right corner. You are only allowed to move one step down or right. After blocking one cell, count the number of paths from top left to bottom right cell. There are always at least 3 empty cell. Two of them are always the start and the finish cell and other one can be any of the remaining cells.

The part of counting the number of paths from top left to bottom right is fairly easy and can be solved easily using dynamic programming.

The part I'm stuck at is the one cell to be blocked to minimize number of paths. Intuition says to search the grid horizontally and block the first cell with max number of incoming and outgoing paths. For example for the grid

```
..## -> Row 1
..##
....
.... -> Row 4
```

I would block (3,2) because that would block most of the path and the number of paths remaining would be just one. But I am not entirely confident this is the correct approach. Any insights?

Comment: You say counting the number of paths is easy. So did you already try brute-forcing the problem by just blocking the free cells individually and using your path-counting algorithm?

Comment: That blocking point should have a maximum sum of paths from the starting point to it and from the ending point to it.

Comment: @knedlsepp That would be O(N^4). There is probably an O(N^2) algorithm.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That's correct, but whenever the naive approach is feasible I'd say: go for that. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp Updated the question with the number of path finding algorithm. And to answer your question, I tried using my intuitive approach instead of brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The part of counting the number of paths from top left to bottom right is fairly easy and can be solved easily using dynamic programming

This algorithm is an excellent starting point. Consider its implementation that uses an array `pathsFromStart[N][N]` to store the number of paths from the starting point to a point at `(row, col)`. Run the algorithm again, but now start at the end . This gives you a second 2D array, `pathsFromFinish[N][N]`.

With this two arrays in hand you are ready to find the answer to your original problem: if a point at `(row,col)` has X paths leading to it from the start, and Y paths leading to it from the finish, then the total number of paths that you would cut by removing that point would be XY. Go through all points on the grid excluding the start, the finish, and the points that are already blocked, and exclude the point with

```
MAX(pathsFromStart[row][col]*pathsFromFinish[row][col])
```

Comment: Well. This certainly makes for a better approach. \*g\* +1

Comment: Ah! It was right there in front of my face all the while.